# JSON format for two points with ccordinates

Tags: json

Folks,
I need to create a JSON data that represent the following request:

> Perform a JSON POST request with following data

pointA

1. x
2. y
3. z

PointB

1. x
2. y
3. z

I am thinking that this should suffice, but apparently the Endpoint (which I dont have access to it's code/format) rejects it.

```
{
  "PointA": {
    "X": 1,
    "Y": 2,
    "Z": 3
  },
  "PointB": {
    "X": 4,
    "Y": 5,
    "Z": 6
  }
}
```

Comment: Specify "rejects it" are there any errors? Did you try different configurations? (like "x" instead of "X", or use the vector format for a point [1, 2, 3])

Comment: I have tried all of them I get "Bad String" or {
  "errorMessage": "invalid data structure"
}

Comment: Did you set correctly the content-type of the request?